# Bethe's mean field approximation and general cluster treatment of Ising model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, mean-field-theory

In Bethe's mean field approximation the Hamiltonian describes only the energy of a central spin $\sigma_0$ and its $q$ nearest neighbors:

$$
H_{BMF}=−h\sigma_0−J\sigma_0\sum_{i=1}^{q}\sigma_i−(h+h')\sum_{i=1}^{q}\sigma_i
$$
where $h'$ is the effective magnetic interaction of the $q$ neighbors with the other lattice sites.

The Ising approximation on the other hand encodes the energy of all $N$ lattice sites replacing the exact interaction between nearest pairs with its mean value:
$$
H_{MF}=\dfrac{NJqm^2}{2}-(h+Jqm)\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sigma_i
$$

Having read the following question:
[Bethe approximation for a three spin cluster](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428309/bethe-approximation-for-a-three-spin-cluster?rq=1)

I'm still confused regarding this part of the answer:

> "all the terms ... are included, but the spin values ... not included explicitly ... are set equal to m, and this gives a large number of constant terms in the sum, which can be dropped as they will not affect the final result"

Like the one who asked the above, I searched for this question because I'm not sure how the first step from Ising model to Bethe's is done - how to move from a description in terms of all sites to a description in terms of one central spin (or cluster).

Moreover, in SM by Pathria & Paul (3rd edition), Ising MF is presented as the zeroth MF approx vs Bethe's as the first. But how are those even compared if one encodes all lattice sites whereas the other is a description of a single cluster? I understand that unlike the Zeroth approx it takes into account the exact interaction with the q nearest neighbors, but isn't that a "trade off" if the size of the system is ignored?

With relation to the answer itself - what is this "large addition" and how can it be disregarded from the final result? Especially in comparison to $H_{MF}$ that does contain the first term that handles all $N$ sites.
Shouldn't $H_{BMF}$ (and hence the partition function) of the entire system sum over all clusters (i.e. all lattice sites) in a similar way?

One last thing that doesn't add up, is the calculation of the average magnetization $m$. How come it is defined over the q nearest neighbors instead of $N$ (so that the self consistency equation is in terms of this $m=\dfrac{1}{q}\sum_{i=1}^{q}<\sigma_i>$ instead of $m=\dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}<\sigma_i>$)?